# OCSP responder to hold the revocation information after cert expiration

Tags: digital-signature, digital-certificate, ocsp

Is it possible to tell the CA's OCSP responder to hold the revocation information for the certificate even after the certification expiration?

I heard it's true, but I have no way to verify it. Maybe there is some RFC draft.. I wasn't able to find any information.

Comment: It depends on OCSP software. Contact your OCSP server vendor.

Comment: @Crypt32 Thank you for the answer, but that's not what I'm looking for. I'd like to know if it's defined (standardized) in some paper (RFC for example). My app does certificate validation. It takes OCSP responses from whichever certificate CA's responder it finds. And I'd like to adapt this feature if it formally exists.